# $\exists x\,\big( x >0 → x^3 < 0\big)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am very confused on learning mathematical logic.

The problem is to determine whether the statement is true or false.
Statement: $\exists x ( x >0 \rightarrow x^3 < 0)$ is true. (the domain is $\mathbb R$.)

I think it is false since there is no $x >0 $ such that $x^3 <0$. However, I am confused on the other solution.

The other solution is:
If predicates $P(x): x >0$ and $Q(x): x^3 <0$ are defined, then $P(-1)$ is always false.
Thus, the predicate $P(-1) \rightarrow Q(-1)$ is also true which implies that there is $x$ such that $x >0 \rightarrow x^3 < 0$ is true. As a result, the statement is true.

I also know that the second solution is false, but I do know know how to exactly describe the faults.

Comment: The second solution is perfectly correct.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Oh my god.... What's the wrong in the first solution?

Comment: The first solution would be correct if the statement you were asking for was $\exists x (x>0\ \mathrm{and}\ x^3<0)$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks a lot !

Comment: I feel that the main challenge here is the sometimes counter-intuitive meaning of logical implication when read as "if ... then". One way to understand why your formula is true is to rewrite $p \to q$ as $\lnot p \lor q$. Your formula becomes $\exists x (\lnot(x>0) \lor x^3<0)$ or equivalently $\exists x (x \leq 0 \lor x^3 < 0)$.

Comment: @CristianGratie Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the universe of discourse be $\mathbb R.$

1. $$\forall x\;\big( x >0 \land x^3 < 0\big)$$    Every $x$ is positive and has a negative cube.

   **False**.
2. $$\exists x\;\big( x >0 \land x^3 < 0\big)$$    Some positive $x$ has a negative cube.

   More literally: some $x$ is positive and has a negative cube.

   **False**.
3. $$\forall x\;\big( x >0 \rightarrow x^3 < 0\big)$$    Every positive $x$ has a negative cube.

   More literally: every $x$ that is positive has a negative cube.

   **False** (disprove by finding a true antecedent and false consequent).
4. $$\exists x\;\big( x >0 \rightarrow x^3 < 0\big)$$    For some $x,$ if it's positive, then its cube is negative.

   This translation is the most literal among the four; it is also the trickiest,  as we are tempted to conflate the symbolic versions of $(2)$ and $(4);$ fortunately, this sentence category is also the least common.

   **True**, as explained by your 2nd solution (prove by finding a false antecedent or true consequent). Clarify the symbolic sentence by equivalently rewriting it as $$\exists x\;\big( x \leq0 \,\lor\, x^3 < 0\big).$$

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. It is very confusing of (2) and (4) as you mentioned. Thanks again.